# ERC20 contract not able to transfer large amount of tokens

Tags: solidity, web3js, erc-20

I am building an ERC20 Token. I want to the decimals properly so that people can do transaction in deciamls also. 
So, I am trying to transfer 10^21 tokens from my address to another.

`Minted tokens : 1000000 * (10**decimals) # decimals = 18`

So, I should have 10^23 tokens in total.

So I should be able to transfer this amount?

I made a UI and used web3.js where I got this error.

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): 
invalid number value (arg="_price", coderType="uint256", value="1e+21")
```

Then I also tried in Remix for the same values. there also the transaction failed.

Execution is failing for numbers like if I want to transfer 10*20 token. then also the transaction fails.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use floating point numbers to interact with cryptocurrency, or any monetary units. You need to use a special helper class called [BigNumber.js](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.8/web3-utils.html#bn) to do the math. Then you convert those numbers to strings before passing them to functions that go to JSON-RPC interface.

Comment: Yeah I am not using floating numbers. That is why I am using decimals to multiply to the floating number and convert to a proper uint. 
I  tried the web3.utils.toBN() I got the error `Error: invalid number value (arg="_price", coderType="uint256", value="1e+21")`

Comment: `Error: [number-to-bn] while converting number 1e+21 to BN.js instance, error: invalid number value. Value must be an integer, hex string, BN or BigNumber instance. Note, decimals are not supported. Given value: "1e+21"`

Comment: `1e+21` is clearly a floating point number in scientific format.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar In javascript there is a [maximum safe integer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER), larger numbers are converted to floating point.

Comment: I found the way to do it. . I have posted an answer also.

Comment: "1e+21" is **NOT** "clearly a floating point number in scientific format". In fact, it clearly has an **integer** value, since it is equivalent to "1" followed by 21 zeros. The only reason it becomes a floating-point variable in Javascript, is because it is larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. But it may very well still represent an integer value.

Comment: And the reason for the actual error in the question is that on Web3.js v1.x (which is what this dude is using according to his answer below), the value passed to the various `BN` functions must be either an integer, a hex string, a `BN` instance or a `BigNumber` instance which represents an integer (since it can also represent a non-integer).

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using this: 
https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/2077#issuecomment-468530879

```
          const dec = window.web3.utils.toBN(this.props.decimals)
          const price_ =  window.web3.utils.toBN(this.Object.value*(100))
          const price ="0x"+ price_.mul(window.web3.utils.toBN(10).pow(dec)).toString("hex")
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
let amt = "0x" + (amount * Math.pow(10, this.Currency[index].token_decimals)).toString(16);
```

Comment: The answer may be correct. But you should provide an explanation with your code.